# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when debugging

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting this error when trying to see the contents of a NSMutableArray:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000021
0x94d5a688 in objc_msgSend ()
```

ViewController.h:

```
@interface PeopleViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *people;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *people;
```

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation PeopleViewController

@synthesize people;
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize our people array with an autoreleased object
    people = [NSMutableArray array];

... Populate the people array with Person objects.

}
```

When I'm at the point where I'm modifying the contents of a cell in the tableview, I'm unable to access the people array in gdb when typing 'po self.people':

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
person = [self.people objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; // <--- 'po self.people' called  
cell.textLabel.text = person.personName;
```

Any ideas why I can't access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
people = [NSMutableArray array];
```

returns an autoreleased array that will be released on the next iteration of the current run loop. You should retain that:

```
people = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
```

and of course release it in your dealloc method.

**However:** Apple engineers have often mentioned in conferences to avoid autoreleased instances like this whenever possible in the iPhone, for performance reasons. Try using alloc/init instead:

```
people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
```

with the corresponding release in the dealloc method. In this case you don't even need to retain (init returns an instance with a retain count of 1, which is what you need).

And justin's comment is correct: you should do this instead:

```
Person *person = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = person.personName;
```

and this should work.

Comment: I don't think the retain message is needed, as the property is marked as "retain".

Comment: But the property isn't being used here, the instance variable is being accessed directly, so the property doesn't matter.

Comment: Exactly as jbrennan says: self.person means a call to the property setter method, while "person" all by itself it's just an assignation to the ivar.

Answer (score 4):

is indexPath.row > [people count]?

Also, why are you doing this:

Person *person = [[Person alloc] init]

You're allocating memory, and then pointing to completely different memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having to fuss with retaining properties by using the `self` notation to call the accessor and setter methods created by the `@synthesize` directive.

When you set the `people` property directly in `viewDidLoad` it sets the property but does nothing for memory management. However, if you set it with `self.people` you actually call the synthesized setter method that because of the `retain` setting of the `@property` directive will automatically retain the assigned array.

As an aside, I would recommend always using `-[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]` instead of a bare init. It is the actual initializer for the class. You can call it with just '1' if you don't know how big it will be. In the past, I have seen odd problem arise from just using bare `init`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the designated initializer of NSMutableArray, I've corrected that in my answer.